# jquery - what is the difference between $(document).ready( and $(document).on('ready page:load'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a question about jQuery.

When i use

```
$(document).ready( function() { alert("!"); } );
```

this alert message worked just once! at the first page. (e.g. index page)

And other pages never work when I move First page to other pages.

But When I use

```
 $(document).on('ready page:load', function() { alert("!"); } );
```

it always worked very well.
What is the difference between these two statement?

Please Let me know.

Comment: the second one is turbolink related

Comment: @apneadiving because turbolink, the first statement didn't work well?

Comment: it works as expected: only on page load. turbolinks doesnt refresh the page when you click links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document).ready(...)` is built in jQuery functionality. It waits for the DOM to load before running the function passed. It will only be called once per page load.

`$(document).on('ready page:load', ...)` is a custom listener that is part of the [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) library.

Turbolinks basically keeps the page from reloading each time you click a link and instead uses JavaScript to swap the page HTML with what the server sends for that link.

Since `$(document).ready(...)` only triggers when the page finishes loading, and Turbolinks keeps the page from reloading, `$(document).ready(...)` will only trigger once whereas `$(document).on('ready page:load')` will trigger whenever Turbolinks loads a new page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() { alert("!"); } );
```

Is roughly equivalent to:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){ alert("!"); });
// or the shorthand
$(function(){ alert("!"); });
```

All of these register a callback function to be run when the document is ready.

[`jQuery.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) can also accept a space separated list of events.

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() { alert("!"); } );
```

Attaches a handler both to [jQuery's ready event](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) and [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) `page:load` event.

Turbolinks speeds up page loading by fetching the target url with AJAX and replacing the content of the current document. Since turbolinks swaps out the content any event handlers which you have attached to elements in the document will be lost.

By attaching the handler when the `page:load` event fires you are ensuring that any non-idempotent transformations are also fired when turbolinks has replaced the content. Otherwise they will only fire on the initial page load or when you manually refresh the browser.

Although in most cases it is better to use idempotent handlers like this:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function(event) {
  $('#bar').on('click', function(){});
});
```

Or delegate events from the document:

```
$(function(){ 
  $(document).on('click', "#bar", function(){});
});
```